# How to add #pragma warning disable 1591 using CodeDom

Tags: codedom

A portion of our app uses code generated using CodeDom.  This code does not need Xml Comments and so we would like to add a

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
```

to those generated files.  Is this possible with CodeDom and if not, then are there other suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: did that answer help? still looking for other ways? did you ever find a good solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(
    new CodeSnippetCompileUnit("#pragma warning disable 1591"),
    sourceWriter, options);
provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(targetUnit, sourceWriter, options);
provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(
    new CodeSnippetCompileUnit("#pragma warning restore 1591"),
    sourceWriter, options);
```

Doesn't translate well (at all) to other languages.
YMMV
-Ian

Answer (score 0):

Looking through all the reflector code, nothing pops up as the "right" way.
However, there might be a way if you are willing to do some post-generation processing.
Using the RegionDirective, place a special token in the RegionText value. Then, once your code is generated, go back and do a string replace.

Since I didn't see anything in the code that enforces matching code regions, you could have a single start code region at the end to enable warnings again.

For example. your tokens could be "#PRAGMA1591" and "#ENABLEWARNINGS." Therefore, after the code is generated you would have

```
#region #PRAGMA1591

...

#region #WARNINGRESTORE
#endregion
```

You would then do a string replace to yield this:

```
#region Disable Warning 1591
#pragma warning disable 1591

...

#pragma warning restore
#endregion
```

Your strings expand like this:

- ## PRAGMA1591 -> Ignore Lack of XML Documentation \n #pragma warning

  disable 1591
- ## region #WARNINGSRESTORE -> #pragma warning restore